# Как перезаписать элемент списка массива ArrayList через map

Tags: java, android, arraylist, map

Хочу понять, как происходит сама операция

```
int b = a.map(...)
.filter(...)
.sum(....);
```

Есть пример, подскажите, что в нем не так, что доработать:

```
class ArrayList<T>{
T[] items;
ArrayList<M> map(Function func){
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
items[i] = func.handle(Items[i])
}
return ArrayList<M>
}
}

interface Function<T, M>{
public M handle(T item);
}
```